# Is Pandas (by default) reusing memory or making copies?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame with rows A,B,C,D and columns say X,Y,Z,T,S.

This comparison returns False which is surprising to me.

`df.iloc[3] is df.loc['D']`

Aren't these just two different ways of accessing the same row?

Does that mean Pandas is not reusing the same memory (as `numpy` does)?
Is Pandas making copies each time we do `df.loc['D']` or `df.iloc[3]`?

Also, I cannot compare the two rows `df.loc['D']` and `df.iloc[3]`
as Python objects with `==` because the `==` seems overridden.
So I don't get True/False but I get a Series back.
That's why I am comparing them by using `is` and I expected to get `True` back.

On the other hand if I set an element
`df.iloc[3]['S'] = 20`
this change is visible also in

`df.loc['D']`

and in the DataFrame `df` as a whole.

So I am confused by this behavior.
Why is it behaving this way?
And what happens under the hood?

Comment: With numpy arrays the `is` test is rarely useful.  And `==` does element by element comparisons.

Comment: Hm... Yeah, I just tried it with a numpy array and it behaves the same way. E.g. if you take two slices `a[1: , 1:]` of some array `a`, they don't compare as equal with `is`. But if you modify some element via one of these slices the changes are visible in both slices and in the original array itself.

Comment: `df.iloc[3] is df.loc[3]` is also False.  `iloc/loc` returns a new Series object.  `is` is only True for the same Python objects. It doesn't test for matching values or other 'content'.

Comment: @hpaulj You mean `df.iloc[3] is df.iloc[3]`, I assume... Yeah, you're right, this returns `False` too. So it's just returning a new Series object each time but internally this new object is pointing to the same memory (to the same array of elements). Seems this is the answer to my question. Right?

Comment: In `numpy` there's an important concept of `view`, which is a new array, but which shares the data buffer.  Some kinds of indexing produce views, others copies.  `pandas` uses `numpy`, but the relation between `frame`, `Series` and their data arrays is more complex.  I'm not familiar with `pandas` documentation in this regard.